# How to create class and deserialize the returned xml response from thirdParty webApi?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am having the following response xml from the thirdParty webApi. i want to get the Order Id from the Xml and save in to my Database and i need other tags like message Error to show to the User. So i want to de-serialize the Responsed xml which is given below. since i am new to this. Please can you help me to de-serialize the following response. Since i don't have a clear idea about it to create a Class for deserialization. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Status>Success</Status>
    <OrderID>159E6B2AE35244DB984384DBD7DC</OrderID>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>1000</Code>
            <Message> StopType not valid. Submitted TripSheet data has been ignored.</Message>
            <Severity>Unknown</Severity>
        </Error>
        <Error>
            <Code>1000</Code>
            <Message> StopType not valid. Submitted TripSheet data has been ignored.</Message>
            <Severity>Unknown</Severity>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</OrderResult>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you will already have the XML as a Stream from the service, so disregard my code for obtaining the Stream, but here is a console app to demonstrate. I generated the `OrderResult` and `OrderResultError` classes by copying your xml to the clipboard and pasting in Visual Studio with Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<OrderResult xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
    <Status>Success</Status>
    <OrderID>159E6B2AE35244DB984384DBD7DC</OrderID>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>1000</Code>
            <Message> StopType not valid. Submitted TripSheet data has been ignored.</Message>
            <Severity>Unknown</Severity>
        </Error>
        <Error>
            <Code>1000</Code>
            <Message> StopType not valid. Submitted TripSheet data has been ignored.</Message>
            <Severity>Unknown</Severity>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</OrderResult>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderResult));
            var orderresult = ser.Deserialize(ms) as OrderResult;

            Console.WriteLine(orderresult.OrderID);
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class OrderResult
    {

        private string statusField;

        private string orderIDField;

        private OrderResultError[] errorsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.statusField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string OrderID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.orderIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.orderIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Error", IsNullable = false)]
        public OrderResultError[] Errors
        {
            get
            {
                return this.errorsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.errorsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class OrderResultError
    {

        private ushort codeField;

        private string messageField;

        private string severityField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort Code
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return this.messageField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.messageField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Severity
        {
            get
            {
                return this.severityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.severityField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```